# Angular5: Iterate Over Enum Using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, ngfor

I am trying to make a structure of some sort that has key value pairs where the key is an identifier like 'equals' and the values are the unicode equivalent html like '\u003D'. Right now I am using an enum, but I am not sure if this is the best structure. Anyways, I need to use this enum (or other structure) to display the unicode characters in a drop down on a page by using a ngFor statement to iterate over my enum and making options which innerHtml correspondes to the unicode character. What is the best way to do this?

Right now my code is as follows:

**enum**

```
export enum Symbols {
  equals = '\u003D'
}
```

**component.ts**

```
symbols: Symbols;
```

**component.html**

```
<select *ngFor="let symbol of symbols">
     <option value="and">{{symbol}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've removed the snippets from this question because they weren't runable javascript.

Comment: If you know what a typescript enum get translated to in javascript, you would not want to `ngFor` it. What you can do is write a custom pipe to make the enum display-suitable and use it on your enum from inside an `ngFor`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To have the enum accessible within the component, you must declare a property, like you did, but instead of declaring it of *type* `Symbols` (using `:`), you should assign `Symbol` to it (using `=`).

To declare a `<select>` with options, you should use the `*ngFor` in the `<option>`s, not in the `<select>`.

Also, to iterate the enum, you must use `Object.keys(symbols)`, which is aliased by `keys(symbol)` in the template below.

[**Stackblitz Demo here.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-enum-select-options?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export enum Symbols {
  equals = '\u003D',
  notEquals = '!='
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p>
      Having the name as label and symbol as value:
      <select>
        <option *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)" [ngValue]="symbols[symbol]">{{symbol}}</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      Having the symbol as label and name as value:
      <select>
        <option *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)" [ngValue]="symbol">{{symbols[symbol]}}</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  keys = Object.keys;
  symbols = Symbols;
}
```

Comment: in angular5 this displays strings and corresponding numbers, use   keys() : Array<string> {
    var keys = Object.keys(this.role);
    return keys.slice(keys.length / 2);
  }

Comment: A required point for those who don't have the values assigned explicitly to the enum, this will display double items (one for value and another for text).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the keyvalue pipe as well, it makes your life easier.

```
<p *ngFor="let enum of TestEnum | keyvalue">
  {{ enum.key }} - {{ enum.value}}
</p>
```